# Can two columns from one table have a foreign key to the same column in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables in a database, Person and Pet.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Person (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE Pet (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    original_owner INT NOT NULL,
    current_owner INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (original_owner)
        REFERENCES Person(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (current_owner)
        REFERENCES Person(id)
)
```

I am trying to reference the previous owner, and the current owner for each pet. I have also tried

```sql
CREATE TABLE Pet (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    original_owner INT NOT NULL,
    current_owner INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (original_owner, current_owner)
        REFERENCES Person(id, id)
)
```

and

```sql
CREATE TABLE Pet (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    original_owner INT NOT NULL,
    current_owner INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (original_owner, current_owner)
        REFERENCES Person(id)
)
```

but I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Is this even possible to accomplish? Or would I have to create some sort of bridge table to accommodate this?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to declare foreign keys separately

Comment: How would I declare foreign keys more separately than in the first example?

Comment: It is possible, but I think the more accepted practice would be to have a third table that holds pets and their owners. You can then select the most recent 2 (or more) when needing the current and original owners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the order I had the tables defined in the script. I had Pet come before Person. Once I put Person above Pet it worked fine. The example in the question was written from my head, as I didn't have the actual code handy when I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pet` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `original_owner` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `current_owner` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  KEY `origin` (`original_owner`),  
  KEY `current` (`current_owner`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `pet`  
  ADD CONSTRAINT `pet_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`current_owner`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`),  
  ADD CONSTRAINT `pet_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`original_owner`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`);
```

Comment: Does the `KEY origin(original_owner)` clause mean that a given owner can only be the original owner of one pet (does it imply uniqueness)?  If so, then there's a problem; a cat breeder can't breed more than one cat, for example.  The foreign key constraints look right; can they not be specified in the CREATE TABLE?  (Most DBMS would allow that; I don't know whether MySQL does.)

Comment: It's not unique key, it's just an index. This should work just fine